# APK installation openssh | network error (check Internet connection and firewall)

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-compose, openssh

I am behind Proxy and cannot hit to apk default repository. I have to go through a corporate repository, which is a snapshot of APK.

I ran this command:

> [stage-1  3/12] RUN apk add openssh --repository=https://artifactory.internal.xyz/alpine-cache/v3.13/main/:

and I can see that https://artifactory.internal.xyz/alpine-cache/v3.13/main/ has x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

But still , for whatever reason, it is still going to https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/**

```sh
#7 0.491 fetch https://artifactory.internal.xyz/alpine-cache/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 3.601 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 24.75 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: network error (check Internet connection and firewall)
#7 24.80 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 45.96 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: network error (check Internet connection and firewall)
#7 46.26 (1/7) Installing openssh-keygen (8.4_p1-r3)
#7 67.47 (2/7) Installing libedit (20191231.3.1-r1)
#7 67.47 ERROR: openssh-keygen-8.4_p1-r3: network error (check Internet connection and firewall)
```

What could be wrong here?

I am following ssh installation through a docker.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh

Comment: I once had similar problems, don't know enough about apk but I customized /etc/apk/repository with the internal repository. After that it worked. So replace the content of /etc/apk/repository with  https://artifactory.internal.xyz/alpine-cache/v3.13/main/ and check again if it's working.

Comment: Thanks @CLNRMN I forget to mention that I am running this command through dockerfile and it is executed when it is building an image. Where will you find /etc/apk ?

Comment: It's in the container, you could override the /etc/apk/repositories in your Dockerfile.